# LoadError: cannot load such file -- faker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

I want to create seed data with Faker library in Ruby on Rails. 
I have included require 'faker' in my seed.rb file and when I run rails db:seed command, there's a load error. I'm wondering why this could happen and how to fix it. My Ruby version is 2.6.5, and Ruby on Rails version is 6.0.2.1.

```
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- faker
/Users/apple/ride_sharing/db/seeds.rb:10:in `<main>'
/Users/apple/ride_sharing/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/apple/ride_sharing/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan: 

Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

This is the full trace after running rails db:seed --trace command.

```
(base) apple@apples-MacBook-Pro-2 ride_sharing % rails db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- faker
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `rescue in require'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:26:in `require'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
/Users/apple/ride_sharing/db/seeds.rb:10:in `<main>'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `block in load_seed'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:676:in `with_inline_jobs'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `load_seed'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:440:in `load_seed'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:331:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
/Users/apple/ride_sharing/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/apple/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/apple/ride_sharing/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan: 

Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

This is my gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'

# Use bootstrap
# gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.4.1'
gem 'bootstrap', '~>4.3.1'

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require:false
gem 'json'
gem 'activerecord-import'
gem "better_errors"
gem "pry-rails"

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'solargraph', group: :development
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: I don't see `gem 'faker'` anywhere in your Gemfile.

Comment: @Unixmonkey oops! I forgot to put gem 'faker'. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Add this line to your `gemfile`

`gem 'faker'`

and run `bundle install`
and after that **restart your server**.

Comment: i already added this before the problem exists. what could've been the problem

Comment: Having the same issue and have added this to my gemfile as well. Any luck, @foggymindedgreenhorn?

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding `faker` to Gemfile, make sure it complies with the environment you are using, otherwise you gonna to get the same error.

For example, I want faker to work in an environment called 'sandbox', then put gem under `group :sandbox do` section of the `Gemfile`, and do `rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=sandbox`.